# If two weighted averages (convex combinations) of the same distinct non-zero values are equal, does that make their weights equal?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Let
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_{i}f_{i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} q_{i}f_{i}, $$
in which
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_{i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} q_{i}  = 1, \;\; p_{i},q_{i}\geq 0 :\forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}, \color{red}n \color{red}\geq \color{red}2$$
and
$$ 0 \,{\color{red}<} f_{i} \neq f_{j} {\color{red}\leq 1} : \forall i \neq j \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\} $$
Can we conclude $ p_{i} = q_{i} : \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Edit: Thank you M. Wind for the straightforward counter-example! The values of $f_{i}$s in my problem are actually non-zero probabilities, so I edited the title and the question to add the extra assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not draw this conclusion.

For example, let $f_1 = 0$, $f_2 = 1$, $f_3 = 2$.

Then $0.5*f_1 + 0*f_2 + 0.5 * f_3 = 1$

Also $0*f_1 +1*f_2 + 0*f_3 = 1$

Comment: Thank you @M. Wind ! Is there a counter-example for the case in which we can guarantee $ f_{i} \neq 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: @user1090820 Sure. $f_1=0.25$,$f_2=0.50$,$f_3=0.75$ should work.

Comment: Thank you @MWind! That answers my question.